# How Ekadashi is performed in Shiva Temples?

Tags: shiva, ekadashi

In vaishnava Temples Ekadashi is performed as by Vaishnava sampradaya.

Is there is any instructions about how to perform Ekadashi in Shiva temples in any Puranas/ Sacred books?

Answer (score 2):

I am not aware in which book you will get the instructions. However in the Tulsi Das Ramayana its clearly mentioned that Lord shiva loves those devotes who worship Ram(Lord Vishnu) and Lord Vishu Loves those who worship-Lord Shiva .
So I believe that on Ekadashi we can perform Abhishek on Lord Shiva's shivLing ,which makes him happy, as its the  day devoted to his beloved lord Vishu and anyone who praise Lord Shiva  on the day, Will get blessings from both Lord shiva and Lord Vishu.

Comment: स्कंद पुराण में एकादशी महात्म्य अध्याय है, जिसमें सालभर की सभी एकादशियों का महत्व भगवान श्रीकृष्ण ने अर्जुन को बताया है। इस अध्याय के अनुसार एकादशी पर भगवान विष्णु की पूजा और विशेष उपायों करने से सौभाग्य बढ़ सकता है। सोमवार और एकादशी का शुभ योग होने से इस दिन विष्णुजी के साथ ही पति-पत्नी को शिव-पार्वती की भी पूजा करनी चाहिए।

Comment: This is English site. Non English languages are not allowed.

Comment: You should cite some sources.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto, all hindu scriptures are in sanskrit (originally). most quotations given in answers are in sanskrit. Everything on this site is just translation from those. Saying 'Non English languages' are not allowed does not make sense. Those who can translate, let them. Otherwise, original is fine. Others will help them translate. Original has the truth, translation usually distorts it.